# how to change UIView in cell when click on any cell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview, background

I to create one `TableView` that has custom cell from `UITableViewCell`. in my custom cell exist `UIView`.

I want when click on any cell change background color UIView that is in `UITableViewCell`.this is my code:

**CustomCell.h**

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIView *Views;
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLable;
@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"
@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize titleLable,Views;
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    NSArray *name;
}
@synthesize table;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    table = [self makeTableView];
    [self.view addSubview:table];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor: RGB(193,60,46)]; //will give a UIColor objct
    name = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];


}
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(UITableView *)makeTableView
{
    CGFloat x = 0;
    CGFloat y = 0;
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    tableView.rowHeight = 60;
    tableView.sectionFooterHeight = 22;
    tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 22;
    tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    tableView.bounces = YES;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;

    return tableView;
}

#pragma mark Table View Data Source Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObject) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLable.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this declare `NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath` in your interface first and initialize it in `viewDidLoad`.

Then change the following `UITableView` delegate and datasource methods

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObject) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]]) {
                cell = (CustomCell *)currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

if (indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath.row && indexPath.section == selectedIndexPath.section){
   [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; // set your own background color here
}else{
   [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // set your own default background color here
  }
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLable.text = [name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I write this code but one problem why when I do to run my code before select any cell my first cell from first section changed background auto??? I want when click any cell this code working not auto...

Comment: check my edited code above.Also initilalize selectedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexpathForRow:-1 inSection:0] in viewDidload

Comment: my friend this code has a little mistake. when run this code for first time selectedIndexPath.row & selectedIndexPath.section have 0 value that it is mistake because auto change background color first cell of first section!!!!! :(

Comment: check my initialization of selectedIndexPath in my previous comment.